# Apply time duration on moving or animate shapes on canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to apply 3 types[appear,animate,disappear] of animation on a shape in canvas.
I want to specify certain time in which all 3 animation to take place,
example : if the user specifies 5min then with in that duration all 3 animation should happen in sequence. so please help in the code.

Comment: This is not a free coding service. Show us what you have, tell us what your specific problem is and we might be able to help you

Comment: I have just started planing on this so thought would get some help.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `window.setTimeout` in the user input handler to start the animations after a specified pause.